# typeid from static method

Tags: c++, static-methods, rtti, typeid

I have the following issue here: I write (refactor) a logger and am trying to use the run time type identification mechanism of C++, specifically `typeid` to get the runtime type information of the class that has just called the logger. This goes into a macro like:

```
#define debug() Streamer(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, typeid(this).name(), LOG_DEBUG)
```

where Streamer is a class overloading the `operator <<` to obtain the required streaming features such as `debug() << "message " << 16;` etc...

The only problem is when I call the `debug()` macro from a static function. Because then the `typeid(this)` goes crazy and complains very correctly that a static method has no `this`.

I would like to hear your opinion and maybe some code snippets about obtaining the class as a string containing the static method which tries to log.

Cheers, f.

Comment: You also can't use that macro in functions outside of classes, e.g. `main`.

Comment: this is also a correct observation :( Deserves +1

Comment: If you using gcc you may extract type from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.  You may not be able to create generic macro that work in both method types.

Comment: FWIW: the output of `typeid(x).name()` isn't always very readable anyway.

Comment: yup, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html helps a little bit for gcc, on windows it's a different story